# How to attach .sql file to my php application

Tags: php, sql, ubuntu

I have a php application code and a *.sql file which was running in windows application.
I am trying to run this in my ubuntu pc. I installed xamp in ubuntu and successfully ran the php code. But the code is not running when I move to page which access the database.
How do I attach .sql file to my php code in ubuntu?
I am new to php and well as sql.

Comment: You don't _"attach"_ an .sql file to your php code; you _import_ your SQL dump into your database, either using a UI like phpMyAdmin, or by using the `mysql` command on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `MySQL` and after you can import the `MySQL file`.

You can follow this link for more instructions.
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-mysql